# Extract html section from string containing html code

Tags: php, regex, joomla

I would extract some section html code from a string.
This string is returned from a php joomla page.
This string contain code like this:

```
<!-- JoomlaWorks "Disqus Comment System for Joomla!" Plugin (v2.2) starts here -->

<div class="itp-fshare-floating" id="itp-fshare" style="position:fixed; top:30px !important; left:50px !important;">
</div>
<p>
    <span class="easy_img_caption"  style="display:inline-block;line-height:0.5;vertical-align:top;background-color:#F2F2F2;text-align:left;width:180px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;">

        <a href="/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13:11111&catid=1:guide-sui-serivzi-cloud-computing&Itemid=3">
            <img src="/joomla/plugins/content/imagesresizecache/441a27b2a4d64b487a8e213a94f6466d.jpeg" border="0" alt="1" title="1"  style="width:180px; height:150px; ;margin:0;" />
        </a>
        <span class="easy_img_caption_inner" style="display:inline-block;line-height:normal;color:#000000;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;padding:4px 8px;margin:0px;">1

        </span>
    </span>

    11111111111111111111111111111111111
</p>

<!-- Disqus comments counter and anchor link -->

<a class="jwDisqusListingCounterLink" href="http://clouderize.it/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13:11111&catid=1:guide-sui-serivzi-cloud-computing&Itemid=3#disqus_thread" title="Add a comment">
    Add a comment
</a>

<!-- JoomlaWorks "Disqus Comment System for Joomla!" Plugin (v2.2) ends here -->
```

I would extract this section:

```
    <span class="easy_img_caption"  style="display:inline-block;line-height:0.5;vertical-align:top;background-color:#F2F2F2;text-align:left;width:180px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;">

        <a href="/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13:11111&catid=1:guide-sui-serivzi-cloud-computing&Itemid=3">
            <img src="/joomla/plugins/content/imagesresizecache/441a27b2a4d64b487a8e213a94f6466d.jpeg" border="0" alt="1" title="1"  style="width:180px; height:150px; ;margin:0;" />
        </a>
        <span class="easy_img_caption_inner" style="display:inline-block;line-height:normal;color:#000000;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;padding:4px 8px;margin:0px;">1

        </span>
    </span>
```

How can I do?
Thanks a lot.

MODIFY1:

```
$content="<html><head></head><body>".($this->item->text)."</body></html>";
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($content);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

        $tags = $xpath->query('//span[@class="easy_img_caption"]/');
        print_r($tags);
```

MODIFY2:
With this code:

```
$content="<html><head></head><body>".($this->item->text)."</body></html>";
        $content=($this->item->text);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        $dom->loadHTML($content);

        $xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

        $tags = $xpath->query('//span[@class="easy_img_caption"]');
        //echo "<textarea>".print_r($dom->saveXml($tags->item(0)))."</textarea>";
        foreach ($tags as $tag) {
            $innerHTML = '';
            $children = $tag->childNodes;
            foreach ($children as $child) {
                $tmp_doc = new DOMDocument();
                $tmp_doc->appendChild($tmp_doc->importNode($child,true));       
                $innerHTML .= $tmp_doc->saveHTML();
            }

            echo $innerHTML;
```

I have returned:

```
<a href="/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13:11111&catid=1:guide-sui-serivzi-cloud-computing&Itemid=3">
    <img src="/joomla/plugins/content/imagesresizecache/441a27b2a4d64b487a8e213a94f6466d.jpeg" border="0" alt="1" title="1" style="width:180px; height:150px; ;margin:0;">
</a>
<span class="easy_img_caption_inner" style="display:inline-block;line-height:normal;color:#000000;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;padding:4px 8px;margin:0px;">1</span>
```

The problem is that I want also the previous span:

```
<span class="easy_img_caption"  style="display:inline-block;line-height:0.5;vertical-align:top;background-color:#F2F2F2;text-align:left;width:180px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;">
```

What modify I have to do at xpath query?

Thanks again.

Comment: *(related)* [Best Methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html/3577662#3577662)

Comment: I am not very good with dom and xmlreader...can you help me with some code?

Comment: sure. have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dom+html+user%3A208809

Comment: Is my xpath query wrong?

Comment: remove the trailing slash and print with `$dom->saveXml($tags->item(0));`. The query methods return a DOMNodeList. Also, when you use loadHTML you dont have to add the HTML skeleton around $this->item because DOM will add that automatically.

Comment: $tags = $xpath->query('//span[@class="easy_img_caption"]');
   print_r($dom->saveXml($tags->item(0)););

Comment: then your HTML is not what you show

Comment: Sorry work but I have returned => 1.....what is? How can I print the html?

Comment: are you viewing the results in a browser? If, so View Source.

Comment: The returned code is missing previous span. See MODIFY 2 in my post.Thanks again.

Comment: `$dom->saveXml($tags->item(0)` already returns the span you want. there is no need to fetch the innerHTML of it.

Comment: but if I do echo $dom->saveXml(....) I have returned: 1.

Comment: can you post me an answer with the correct code? Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4764/discussion-between-michele-and-gordon)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution for your test string using PHPQuery library http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/:

```
<?php

require('phpQuery/phpQuery.php');

$testString =

'<!-- JoomlaWorks "Disqus Comment System for Joomla!" Plugin (v2.2) starts here -->

<div class="itp-fshare-floating" id="itp-fshare" style="position:fixed; top:30px !        important; left:50px !important;">
</div>
<p>
<span class="easy_img_caption"  style="display:inline-block;line-height:0.5;vertical-align:top;background-color:#F2F2F2;text-align:left;width:180px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;">

    <a href="/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13:11111&catid=1:guide-sui-serivzi-cloud-computing&Itemid=3">
        <img src="/joomla/plugins/content/imagesresizecache/441a27b2a4d64b487a8e213a94f6466d.jpeg" border="0" alt="1" title="1"  style="width:180px; height:150px; ;margin:0;" />
    </a>
    <span class="easy_img_caption_inner" style="display:inline-block;line-height:normal;color:#000000;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;padding:4px 8px;margin:0px;">1

    </span>
</span>

11111111111111111111111111111111111
</p>

<!-- Disqus comments counter and anchor link -->

<a class="jwDisqusListingCounterLink" href="http://clouderize.it/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=13:11111&catid=1:guide-sui-serivzi-cloud-computing&Itemid=3#disqus_thread" title="Add a comment">
Add a comment
</a>

<!-- JoomlaWorks "Disqus Comment System for Joomla!" Plugin (v2.2) ends here -->';

$doc = phpQuery::newDocument($testString);

$extraction=pq('.easy_img_caption:eq(0)')->htmlOuter();

echo  $extraction;

/* outputs
<span class="easy_img_caption" style="display:inline-block;line-height:0.5;vertical-    align:top;background-color:#F2F2F2;text-align:left;width:180px;float:left;margin:0px 10px;">

    <a href="/joomla/index.php?option=com_content&amp;view=article&amp;id=13:11111&amp;catid=1:guide-sui-serivzi-cloud-computing&amp;Itemid=3">
        <img src="/joomla/plugins/content/imagesresizecache/441a27b2a4d64b487a8e213a94f6466d.jpeg" border="0" alt="1" title="1" style="width:180px; height:150px; ;margin:0;"></a>
    <span class="easy_img_caption_inner" style="display:inline-block;line-height:normal;color:#000000;font-size:8pt;font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;padding:4px 8px;margin:0px;">1

    </span>
</span>
*/

?>
```

Comment: Hi, but with DOM how can I do? Thanks I appreciate this, but I would prefer not to use external libs.